# Shrinkwrap an image to a cylindrical / slightly conical object with minimal distortion

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, photorealism, shrinkwrap

I have some five gallon buckets of various different dimensions and artwork for a label that would go on them. I'm trying to figure out how I can show the label applied to a bucket accurately.

The label files are on an 11" x 17" template. The area beyond the die line is transparent. The die line itself is an irregular shape. I've included a picture of the test label I'm using. (The 11x17 template could be cropped down to be closer to the size of the die line but it would be preferable to leave it as is if possible.)

Here's how I currently have it applied:

- Created an 11" x 17" plane
- Used the test label as an image texture
- Added some loop cuts to *fold* the plane around the bucket
- Used the edges of those loop cuts as a pivot point when rotating to maintain the overall length of the plane
- Added a shrinkwrap modifier to the plane targetting the bucket and using an offset of 0.03"

The example bucket used has a larger radius on the top than on the bottom.

The distortion on the squares might seem minor overall but it's quite noticeable when using the real label art.

I want to avoid *eyeballing* and arbitrarily stretching things as much as possible. Some buckets I might not have a physical reference of to tape up a test label to so I want to be able to trust in my technique used.

It's also slightly suspicious how the rendered label art doesn't curve around the bucket quite as far as the real life photo but I think that might have more to do with slight camera differences than anything else.

I'm using blender 2.8.

Let me know if there's anything else I can add to clarify.

[image]

IRL bucket with label[image: real bucket]

Shrinkwrap modifier
[image: squares in middle appear squeezed slightly]

Test label
[image: label with test pattern]

Comment: Is there a reason you need the image to be a separate object instead of just an image texture on the bucket?

Comment: The main reason is it seemed like easiest way to have an area of a specific size to move around as opposed to trying to unwrap the bucket object and try to adjust the uv mapping.

Comment: Can't you just assign the part of the bucket with the texture to a separate material, and then you don't need any uv mapping?

Comment: The label is an irregular shape, how would I assign that material without uv mapping? I also do not want to have faces just for the purposes of being a label since there's multiple shapes of label that would be used with a particular bucket. I think I might not be properly understanding your suggestion.

Comment: I think you are right, if you want to be able to move around the label easily, than a separate object is a good idea.